# Relation between Warlock Lord and Allanon in The Shannara Chronicles

Tags: character, the-shannara-chronicles

What is the relation between *Warlock Lord* and *Allanon* in ***The Shannara Chronicles***? The two characters are played by the same person **Manu Bennet** in the TV series. It is also shown that both are druids.

What more do they have in common? What has been said about the Warlock Lord in the books?

Comment: That's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## He has his body because it was Allanon's blood used in the ritual.

The Warlock Lord was resurrected using the blood of Allanon, thus the Warlock Lord took his form. Here's the article that summarizes it nicely.

> In last week's double-header of The Shannara Chronicles, fans got to see Bandon (Marcus Vanco) finally resurrect the Warlock Lord after almost an entire season of build-up. In a surprising twist, the Warlock Lord took the human form of Manu Bennett's Allanon, since the ritual was performed using Allanon's blood.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[The Warlock Lord Speaks in Shannara Chronicles Season 2 Finale - ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/shannara-chronicles-season-2-finale-video/)</sub>

In specific, Bandon used his sword which had Allanon's blood all over it to draw the runes for the ritual.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215098/why-did-the-warlock-lord-have-the-face-of-allanon) answer on [scifi.stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) it states that due to the fact that Warlock Lord was resurrected using Allanon's blood he was having the same face as Allanon.

[image: Warlock Lord]
Bandon managed to obtain the Warlock Sword from the Dagda Mor, and later, he found the heart of the Warlock Lord in Skull Mountain. By holding Flick ransom, he was also able to coerce Wil Ohmsford and Mareth into retrieving the skull of the Warlock Lord and bringing it to him. With these three items, Bandon was able to resurrect the Warlock Lord inside of Graymark, the Warlock Lord's former fortress.